# Getting data from service however object is empty

Tags: c#, .net, json, web-services, c#-4.0

```
var details= _clientService.GetAsync<DoctorDetails>(getDetails).Result;
```

I get the Result from the service which is JSON when I use "object" in the GetAsync instead of DoctorDetails. However, I don't see any property values being filled in details (All are null in DoctorDetails). DoctorDetails is the cs file of the schema I generated through xsd.

DoctorDetails is an auto generated file that contains properties like

Name
ID etc

How to deserialize this and get values in those properties (in the details variable above)

**Edit**

It is only returning values if I make the syntax like this

```
var details= _clientService.GetAsync<object>(getDetails).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already tried this option, use a library called Json.Net from Newtonsoft for json stuff. [Newtonsoft json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

Provided you have the schema details and the property names match you may try the following..

```
    var details= _clientService.GetAsync<object>(getDetails).Result;//Please check if this is a string else use .ToString()
    /*
    "{
      'Name': 'Doctor Who',
      'ID' : '1001' 
        }";
     */
    DoctorDetails m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DoctorDetails>(details);
```

Documentation [Deserialize an Object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm).
I'm not promoting this library, it's just a suggestion. :)
Hope it helps.

Comment: So does this return anything `var details= _clientService.GetAsync<object>(getDetails).Result` ? Are you able to share the result (or snippet) if possible? Unless you are saying that is also null..